# Why am I getting duplicate entry errors after MySQL upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0?

Tags: mysql

So we just upgraded from MySQL 5.7-ubuntu to 8.0. The upgrade seems to have went smoothly, however now we're getting "Duplicate entry" errors every time we try to INSERT.

Investigation has revealed that all the AI (auto increment) values in the DB (on all tables) are set to the ***last used*** ID in the table, so it's attempting to INSERT on an existing ID.

I believe that manually bumping the AI value by one on each table should resolve this, but I am curious/concerned about why it happened in the first place. It may be indicative of other issues.

Can someone explain why this happened?
(I tried searching this, but enormous amounts of false positives)

Thanks

Comment: What are AI values?

Comment: @mihai auto increment

Comment: @Spot What were your steps to upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0? Have you used a mysqldump? If yes, are there any statements in the file where the auto increment value is set? Have you run the mysql_upgrade command (if required)? It is possible that you can somehow provide a [mcve], which will result in the same duplicate entry error?

Comment: @Progman I did use mysqldump, but was not required  to (and did not) import the dumps. It performed the upgrade in place, and my data was still there and perceptibly in tact. I was thinking I may want to wipe the DB and import the data from the dumps, but was wanting to get more info before going that route.
Providing a reproducible example would be extremely difficult in this case, which is why I didn't do that to begin with.

Comment: @Progman As a bit more clarification, I used the apt method of upgrading, according to MySQL.com's instructions.

Comment: @Spot What was the exact original MySQL version and what is the exact upgraded MySQL version?

Comment: @Progman `5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` -> `8.0.16` It turns out it was the `autoinc_lock_mode` value, which shifted defaults between the two versions. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one explains how its handled in 5.7 and 8

AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: I went through this before, but you mentioning it here caused me to pick through it more carefully. I missed the part about the change in default `autoinc_lock_mode` between 5.7 and 8.0. Forcing it back to `1` seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for the pointer.